# IDN support not enabled for cURL

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I am having some issue getting an image into a dynamic memory buffer with cURL.

The bit of code used is the following:

```
struct memoryStruct {
  char *memory;
  size_t size;
};

static void* CURL_realloc(void *ptr, size_t size)
{
  /* There might be a realloc() out there that doesn't like reallocing
     NULL pointers, so we take care of it here */
  if(ptr)
    return realloc(ptr, size);
  else
    return malloc(size);
}

size_t WriteMemoryCallback(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *data)
{
  size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
  struct memoryStruct *mem = (struct memoryStruct *)data;

  mem->memory = (char *)CURL_realloc(mem->memory, mem->size + realsize + 1);

  if (mem->memory) 
  {
    memcpy(&(mem->memory[mem->size]), ptr, realsize);
    mem->size += realsize;
    mem->memory[mem->size] = 0;
  }

  return realsize;
}




int main()
{
  std::string everything = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1e/Stonehenge.jpg";
  CURL *curl;       // CURL objects
  CURLcode res;
  memoryStruct buffer; // memory buffer

  curl = curl_easy_init(); // init CURL library object/structure

  if(curl) {

        // set up the write to memory buffer
        // (buffer starts off empty)

        buffer.memory = NULL;
        buffer.size = 0;

        // (N.B. check this URL still works in browser in case image has moved)

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, everything);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); // tell us what is happening

        // tell libcurl where to write the image (to a dynamic memory buffer)

        curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *) &buffer);

        // get the image from the specified URL

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);


        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        free(buffer.memory);

  }
  return 0;
}
```

As an error output I get the error saying the following:
[image]

I am however not sure to understand the error being displayed. My guess is that I should enable IDN support for curl? I am however not sure on how to proceed. Does that mean that I would have to recompile the library with IDN enabled? (If I find how to do it)

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing an `std::string` object to `curl_easy_setopt`, while you should be passing a C string. It's actually trying to resolve god-knows-what.

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, everything.c_str());
```